# Update the date in an edittext - Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I want to put the DatePicker's Date in an EditText and keep updating this edittext as the person changes the date. Someone help me?

this is my code:

```
private View view;

    private Button next;
    private EditText birthday;
    private DatePicker datePicker;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_birthday, container, false);

        initWidgets();

        int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = datePicker.getMonth();
        int year = datePicker.getYear();

        birthday.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

        return view;
    }

    private void initWidgets() {
        next = view.findViewById(R.id.bt5);
        birthday = view.findViewById(R.id.kz5);
        datePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    }
```

xml code:

```
<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener to listen the change on DatePicker, like this:

```
    datePicker.init(2021, 1, 1, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // use year month day here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok, I did that, I tried to do `birthday.setText(year + monthOfYear + dayOfMonth);`, but then the app closes, can you tell me why?

Comment: year, month and day are integers, you need to convert to string, like
"" + year + "/" + monthOfYear+ "," + dayOfMonth

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code without xml required, it will help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, 2021, 1, 1);
      datePickerDialog.show();
    }
  });
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Log.d("selectedDate",""+year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in your layout set edittext as `android:enabled="false"` or do it programmatically as `edtDate.setEnabled(false);`

And set click event to open date picker.

```
edtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        edtDate.setText(String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.format("%02d", (monthOfYear + 1)) + "-" + String.format("%02d", year));
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without opening a dialog? Because I put the calendar in "spinner" mode by xml

Comment: Yes, define a listener for your datepicker and you will receive updated data in "onDateSet" function.